# Removal of Smart Web Search from system

Tags: malware, search-engines, hijack

Somehow *Smart Web Search* has been activated in my system. When I searched about it, I figured out that it's a hijacker program.

Is there any way to remove this thing? I tried to remove it but was unable to do so.

Comment: What removal methods have you tried? Just so we don't go and suggest something you have already seen.

Comment: @MichaelFrank I followed this link to remove Smart Web Search, but no success   http://www.pcinfected.com/smart-web-search-removal/